# Power Query does not stop loading lines after table ended

Tags: loading, powerquery

Well, my problem is basically what the title says: I have a table that retrieves data from a table in another excel file, and now, doesn't stop loading lines, well after said table ended.

The script that I have (see bellow), has another table innerjoined, but that table, also from PowerQuery, that retrieves a table from yet another excel file, loads just fine. No problems. The main one is the one that does not stop until like 3000000 lines (original table is 3000 lines).

I can't understand the problem, because this has been working just fine.

```
let
Origem = Excel.Workbook(File.Contents("\\SERVIDOR\Registo de defeitos\REGISTO_DEFEITOS_2016.xlsm"), null, true),
REGISTRY_Table = Origem{[Item="REGISTRY",Kind="Table"]}[Data],
#"Tipo Alterado" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(REGISTRY_Table,{{"FINDER", type text}, {"DATA", type date}, {"ORDEM FABRICO", Int64.Type}, {"REFERÊNCIA", Int64.Type}, {"LOTE", type text}, {"OPERADOR", type text}, {"PRENSA", Int64.Type}, {"TURNO", Int64.Type}, {"PRODUÇÃO TOTAL#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", Int64.Type}, {"A", Int64.Type}, {"B", Int64.Type}, {"C", Int64.Type}, {"D", Int64.Type}, {"E", Int64.Type}, {"F", Int64.Type}, {"Z", Int64.Type}, {"L", Int64.Type}, {"M", Int64.Type}, {"N", Int64.Type}, {"O", Int64.Type}, {"P", Int64.Type}, {"QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(PRENSA)", Int64.Type}, {"QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(PRENSA)", Int64.Type}, {"% DEFEITOS#(lf)(PRENSA)", type number}, {"% DETECÇÃO DE DEFEITOS#(lf)(PRENSA)", type number}, {"DATA DE INSPECÇÃO", type date}, {"QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS VERIFICADA#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", Int64.Type}, {"TIPO DE INSPECÇÃO", type text}, {"A ", Int64.Type}, {"B ", Int64.Type}, {"C ", Int64.Type}, {"D ", Int64.Type}, {"E ", Int64.Type}, {"F ", Int64.Type}, {"Z ", Int64.Type}, {"L ", Int64.Type}, {"M ", Int64.Type}, {"N ", Int64.Type}, {"O ", Int64.Type}, {"P ", Int64.Type}, {"PEÇAS RETRABALHADAS ""OK""#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", Int64.Type}, {"LOTE#(lf)FECHADO", type text}, {"QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", Int64.Type}, {"QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", Int64.Type}, {"% DEFEITOS#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", type number}, {"QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(FINAL)", Int64.Type}, {"QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(FINAL)", Int64.Type}, {"% DEFEITOS#(lf)(FINAL)", type number}, {"CONTABILIZAÇÃO DE PEÇAS", Int64.Type}, {"TESTER", Int64.Type}, {"MÊS", type text}, {"ANO", Int64.Type}, {"MÊS INSP.", type text}, {"ANO INSP.", Int64.Type}}),
#"Colunas Removidas" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Tipo Alterado",{"TESTER"}),
#"Consultas Intercaladas" = Table.NestedJoin(#"Colunas Removidas",{"FINDER"},TabelaRegistos,{"FINDER"},"NewColumn",JoinKind.Inner),
#"Expandido NewColumn" = Table.ExpandTableColumn(#"Consultas Intercaladas", "NewColumn", {"Nº DE CAVIDADES", "PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA (nº de cargas/h)", "AJUSTE DE OBJECTIVO PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA#(lf)(nº de cargas/h)", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL#(lf)(nº de peças)", "A   ", "B   ", "C   ", "D   ", "E   ", "F   ", "G   ", "H   ", "I   ", "Z   ", "PRENSA SEM PARAGEM PARA REFEIÇÕES?", "J   ", "TEMPO DE PARAGEM NÃO PROGRAMADA (min)", "TEMPO DE PARAGEM PROGRAMADA (min)", "AJUSTE DE TEMPO DE TURNO#(lf)(min)", "LOTE FECHADO", "OBSERVAÇÕES", "PRODUÇÃO EFECTIVA#(lf)(nº de cargas/h)", "PERFORMANCE#(lf)(%)", "DISPONIBILIDADE#(lf)(%)", "QUALIDADE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "QUALIDADE#(lf)(%)", "OEE OBJECTIVO#(lf)(%)", "WE OBJECTIVO#(lf)(%)", "OEE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "OEE#(lf)(%)", "Δ OEE#(lf)(Δ%)", "WE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "WE#(lf)(%)", "Δ WE#(lf)(Δ%)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO DISPONÍVEL#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS NÃO PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE LABORAÇÃO EFECTIVO#(lf)(min)", "EFICÁCIA DE UTILIZAÇÃO#(lf)(%)", "FINDER", "COMMENTS", "NOME MÊS", "AProg", "BProg", "CProg", "DProg", "EProg", "FProg", "GProg", "HProg", "IProg", "Zprog", "ANProg", "BNProg", "CNProg", "DNProg", "ENProg", "FNProg", "GNProg", "HNProg", "INProg", "ZNprog"}, {"Nº DE CAVIDADES", "PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA (nº de cargas/h)", "AJUSTE DE OBJECTIVO PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA#(lf)(nº de cargas/h)", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL#(lf)(nº de peças)", "A   ", "B   ", "C   ", "D   ", "E   ", "F   ", "G   ", "H   ", "I   ", "Z   ", "PRENSA SEM PARAGEM PARA REFEIÇÕES?", "J   ", "TEMPO DE PARAGEM NÃO PROGRAMADA (min)", "TEMPO DE PARAGEM PROGRAMADA (min)", "AJUSTE DE TEMPO DE TURNO#(lf)(min)", "LOTE FECHADO", "OBSERVAÇÕES", "PRODUÇÃO EFECTIVA#(lf)(nº de cargas/h)", "PERFORMANCE#(lf)(%)", "DISPONIBILIDADE#(lf)(%)", "QUALIDADE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "QUALIDADE#(lf)(%)", "OEE OBJECTIVO#(lf)(%)", "WE OBJECTIVO#(lf)(%)", "OEE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "OEE#(lf)(%)", "Δ OEE#(lf)(Δ%)", "WE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "WE#(lf)(%)", "Δ WE#(lf)(Δ%)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO DISPONÍVEL#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS NÃO PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE LABORAÇÃO EFECTIVO#(lf)(min)", "EFICÁCIA DE UTILIZAÇÃO#(lf)(%)", "FINDER.1", "COMMENTS", "NOME MÊS", "AProg", "BProg", "CProg", "DProg", "EProg", "FProg", "GProg", "HProg", "IProg", "Zprog", "ANProg", "BNProg", "CNProg", "DNProg", "ENProg", "FNProg", "GNProg", "HNProg", "INProg", "ZNprog"}),
#"Colunas Removidas1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Expandido NewColumn",{"PRODUÇÃO TOTAL#(lf)(nº de peças)"}),
#"Personalizado Adicionado" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colunas Removidas1", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (Nº DE PEÇAS)", each [Nº DE CAVIDADES]*[#"PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA (nº de cargas/h)"]*[#"TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS NÃO PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)"]/60),
#"Tipo Alterado1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personalizado Adicionado",{{"PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (Nº DE PEÇAS)", Int64.Type}}),
#"Trimestre Inserido" = Table.AddColumn(#"Tipo Alterado1", "TRIMESTRE", each Date.QuarterOfYear([DATA]), type number),
#"Personalizado Adicionado1" = Table.AddColumn(#"Trimestre Inserido", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (TEMPO EFECTIVO)", each [Nº DE CAVIDADES]*[#"PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA (nº de cargas/h)"]*[#"TEMPO DE LABORAÇÃO EFECTIVO#(lf)(min)"]/60),
#"Tipo Alterado2" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Personalizado Adicionado1",{{"PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (TEMPO EFECTIVO)", Int64.Type}}),
#"Colunas com Nome Mudado" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Tipo Alterado2",{{"PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (Nº DE PEÇAS)", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (TEMPO COM PARAGENS NÃO PROGRAMADAS)"}}),
#"Colunas Reordenadas" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Colunas com Nome Mudado",{"FINDER", "DATA", "ORDEM FABRICO", "REFERÊNCIA", "LOTE", "OPERADOR", "PRENSA", "TURNO", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "Z", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(PRENSA)", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(PRENSA)", "% DEFEITOS#(lf)(PRENSA)", "% DETECÇÃO DE DEFEITOS#(lf)(PRENSA)", "DATA DE INSPECÇÃO", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS VERIFICADA#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", "TIPO DE INSPECÇÃO", "A ", "B ", "C ", "D ", "E ", "F ", "Z ", "L ", "M ", "N ", "O ", "P ", "PEÇAS RETRABALHADAS ""OK""#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", "LOTE#(lf)FECHADO", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", "% DEFEITOS#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(FINAL)", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(FINAL)", "% DEFEITOS#(lf)(FINAL)", "CONTABILIZAÇÃO DE PEÇAS", "MÊS", "ANO", "MÊS INSP.", "ANO INSP.", "Nº DE CAVIDADES", "PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA (nº de cargas/h)", "AJUSTE DE OBJECTIVO PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA#(lf)(nº de cargas/h)", "A   ", "B   ", "C   ", "D   ", "E   ", "F   ", "G   ", "H   ", "I   ", "Z   ", "PRENSA SEM PARAGEM PARA REFEIÇÕES?", "J   ", "TEMPO DE PARAGEM NÃO PROGRAMADA (min)", "TEMPO DE PARAGEM PROGRAMADA (min)", "AJUSTE DE TEMPO DE TURNO#(lf)(min)", "LOTE FECHADO", "OBSERVAÇÕES", "PRODUÇÃO EFECTIVA#(lf)(nº de cargas/h)", "PERFORMANCE#(lf)(%)", "DISPONIBILIDADE#(lf)(%)", "QUALIDADE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "QUALIDADE#(lf)(%)", "OEE OBJECTIVO#(lf)(%)", "WE OBJECTIVO#(lf)(%)", "OEE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "OEE#(lf)(%)", "Δ OEE#(lf)(Δ%)", "WE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "WE#(lf)(%)", "Δ WE#(lf)(Δ%)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO DISPONÍVEL#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS NÃO PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE LABORAÇÃO EFECTIVO#(lf)(min)", "EFICÁCIA DE UTILIZAÇÃO#(lf)(%)", "FINDER.1", "COMMENTS", "NOME MÊS", "TRIMESTRE", "AProg", "BProg", "CProg", "DProg", "EProg", "FProg", "GProg", "HProg", "IProg", "Zprog", "ANProg", "BNProg", "CNProg", "DNProg", "ENProg", "FNProg", "GNProg", "HNProg", "INProg", "ZNprog", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (TEMPO COM PARAGENS NÃO PROGRAMADAS)", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (TEMPO EFECTIVO)"}),
#"Colunas Removidas2" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Colunas Reordenadas",{"FINDER.1", "FINDER"}),
#"Personalizado Adicionado2" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colunas Removidas2", "PERFORMANCE LÍQUIDA (%)", each [#"QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(FINAL)"]/[#"PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (TEMPO EFECTIVO)"]),
#"Colunas Removidas3" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Personalizado Adicionado2",{"NOME MÊS"}),
#"Colunas Reordenadas1" = Table.ReorderColumns(#"Colunas Removidas3",{"DATA", "ORDEM FABRICO", "REFERÊNCIA", "LOTE", "OPERADOR", "PRENSA", "TURNO", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", "A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "Z", "L", "M", "N", "O", "P", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(PRENSA)", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(PRENSA)", "% DEFEITOS#(lf)(PRENSA)", "% DETECÇÃO DE DEFEITOS#(lf)(PRENSA)", "DATA DE INSPECÇÃO", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS VERIFICADA#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", "TIPO DE INSPECÇÃO", "A ", "B ", "C ", "D ", "E ", "F ", "Z ", "L ", "M ", "N ", "O ", "P ", "PEÇAS RETRABALHADAS ""OK""#(lf)(Nº DE PEÇAS)", "LOTE#(lf)FECHADO", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", "% DEFEITOS#(lf)(INSP. FINAL)", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS OK#(lf)(FINAL)", "QUANTIDADE DE PEÇAS NOK#(lf)(FINAL)", "% DEFEITOS#(lf)(FINAL)", "CONTABILIZAÇÃO DE PEÇAS", "MÊS", "TRIMESTRE", "ANO", "MÊS INSP.", "ANO INSP.", "Nº DE CAVIDADES", "PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA (nº de cargas/h)", "AJUSTE DE OBJECTIVO PRODUÇÃO PREVISTA#(lf)(nº de cargas/h)", "A   ", "B   ", "C   ", "D   ", "E   ", "F   ", "G   ", "H   ", "I   ", "Z   ", "PRENSA SEM PARAGEM PARA REFEIÇÕES?", "J   ", "TEMPO DE PARAGEM NÃO PROGRAMADA (min)", "TEMPO DE PARAGEM PROGRAMADA (min)", "AJUSTE DE TEMPO DE TURNO#(lf)(min)", "LOTE FECHADO", "OBSERVAÇÕES", "PRODUÇÃO EFECTIVA#(lf)(nº de cargas/h)", "PERFORMANCE#(lf)(%)", "DISPONIBILIDADE#(lf)(%)", "QUALIDADE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "QUALIDADE#(lf)(%)", "OEE OBJECTIVO#(lf)(%)", "WE OBJECTIVO#(lf)(%)", "OEE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "OEE#(lf)(%)", "Δ OEE#(lf)(Δ%)", "WE PRENSA#(lf)(%)", "WE#(lf)(%)", "Δ WE#(lf)(Δ%)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO DISPONÍVEL#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE TRABALHO COM PARAGENS NÃO PROGRAMADAS#(lf)(min)", "TEMPO DE LABORAÇÃO EFECTIVO#(lf)(min)", "EFICÁCIA DE UTILIZAÇÃO#(lf)(%)", "COMMENTS", "AProg", "BProg", "CProg", "DProg", "EProg", "FProg", "GProg", "HProg", "IProg", "Zprog", "ANProg", "BNProg", "CNProg", "DNProg", "ENProg", "FNProg", "GNProg", "HNProg", "INProg", "ZNprog", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (TEMPO COM PARAGENS NÃO PROGRAMADAS)", "PRODUÇÃO TOTAL OBJECTIVO (TEMPO EFECTIVO)", "PERFORMANCE LÍQUIDA (%)"}),
#"Personalizado Adicionado3" = Table.AddColumn(#"Colunas Reordenadas1", "100%", each 1),
#"Personalizado Adicionado4" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personalizado Adicionado3", "90%", each 0.9),
#"Personalizado Adicionado5" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personalizado Adicionado4", "85%", each 0.85),
#"Personalizado Adicionado6" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personalizado Adicionado5", "80%", each 0.80),
#"Personalizado Adicionado7" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personalizado Adicionado6", "70%", each 0.70),
#"Personalizado Adicionado8" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personalizado Adicionado7", "60%", each 0.60),
#"Personalizado Adicionado9" = Table.AddColumn(#"Personalizado Adicionado8", "50%", each 0.50)
in
#"Personalizado Adicionado9"
```

Thanks to all that can help.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something is wrong with your key values:
1 Excel table can not have 3 million lines as the maximum is just over 1 million, so logically the source of your issue is at the step where the nested table is expanded: #"Expandido NewColumn".

I ran a small test with 2 tables, each with keys 1-10 and an inner join resulting in a table with 10 rows. So far so good.
Next I emptied the contents of the key columns of each table and ran the query again, resulting in 10 x 10 = 100 rows as each key in either table corresponds with 10 keys in the other table.

So my suggestion would be to verify the values in your FINDER columns.

If this is not the cause, then please share: which is the first step that is causing the issue: you can check each step in the Query Editor.